# Cakephp Security component blackholes delete post

Tags: security, cakephp

I'm sending a delete post from an organisation page to a people controller like this:

```
 $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), 
            array('controller'=> 'people', 'action' => 'delete', 
            $person['id'], 'referer' ), 
            null, 
            __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?',
             $person['firstname']));
```

In the people controller i am setting cross controller communication like this:

```
 $this->Security->allowedControllers = array("people", "company");
```

Yet i still get sent to a black hole.  Why?

Comment: Is `company` the controller for the organization page you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to write controllernames as a plural by convention?

So in this case you would set:

```
$this->Security->allowedControllers = array('peoples', 'companies');
```

And i don't think you need peoples in the array since that's the controller recieving the request. I am still learning cakePHP though, so i might be mistaking.

Comment: no, the singular / plural is Person model, people table - cake is cleverer than you think